# Pirate language in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create a function that changes

> "cat" to "cocatot"

by putting an 'o' if a consonant is detected and repeating the same consonant after that.

This is what I have came up with so far.

UPDATED (cleaner version)

```
isConsonant letter = notElem letter "aeiouy"
sky :: [a] -> [a]
--sky [a] = [a]
sky [] = []
sky (x:rest) = if isConsonant x then x : 'o' : [x] ++ sky rest else x : sky rest
```

and get these errors

```
 * Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `a'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          sky :: forall a. [a] -> [a]

 * In the first argument of `isConsonant', namely `(x)'
      In the expression: isConsonant (x)
      In the expression:
        if isConsonant (x) then
            x : ('o' : [x]) ++ sky (rest)
        else
            x : sky (rest)
```

Any help is really appreciated. I am a beginner in Haskell and I am getting nowhere.

Comment: Can you compute`sky [True, False]`? According to the type you have assigned it, you should be able to. What is the result?

Comment: @n.m I apologize, I am a newbie and am not sure I understand what you mean. I can't get the program to run at all.

Comment: Offtopic notes: `['a','e','i','o','u','y']` is exactly the same as `"aeiouy"`; `x : ('o' : [x]) ++ sky(rest)` is better written `x: 'o' : x : sky rest`; you don't need parentheses to call a function; the `sky [a] = [a]` case is erroneous and should be deleted.

Comment: You expect `sky "cat"` to return `"cocatot"`, presumably because you have calculate it with pencil and paper or in your head or whatever. Using the same mode of calculations, what do you expect `sky [True, False]` to return?

Comment: @ n.m. I am not sure. I think it will return just 'o'. I don't really know.

Comment: A function of type `[a]->[a]` should return the same kind of list it gets as its argument. `[True, False]` is a list of `Bool` and `'o'` is a character and not a list at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer to you type checking error. You declare `sky` as working with any list of `a` but `isConsonant` work only with `Char`, therefore `sky` can only work with list if `Char` too.

Solution :  fix `sky` type signature to `String -> String`  or even just remove it.